# Xamarin.iOS 10 UIButtons adding TouchDown

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have 10 buttons in a view.
I create a first button variable, btnFirst, and then set tags for 10 buttons from 1 to 10.
I want to use one touch down handler for these buttons, so used following code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        UIButton btnOther = (UIButton)this.View.ViewWithTag (btnFirst.Tag + i);
        btnOther.SetTitle (i.ToString(), UIControlState.Normal);
        btnOther.TouchDown += handler;
    }

    void handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    { 
    }
```

But it was crashed.
I know Garbage Collector release 'btnOther'. If so should I create 10 buttons and link them to variables?

Comment: When you calling that method? ViewDidLoad()?

Comment: Add the buttons to a list, you need to store them somewhere